# warning: incompatible Objective-C types

Tags: iphone, uifont

> Warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct UIFont *' when passing argument 1 of 'setFont:' from distinct Objective-C type

Code Like:

```
lblTemp.font = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Arial"]; // Warning comes here    
lblTemp.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:13];    
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];    
[lblTemp release];
```

Please give some suggestion to solve to it.

Answer (score 5):

`-fontNamesForFamilyName:` returns an array of font names, not a `UIFont`. You'll want to pass one of the strings in this array to `+[UIFont fontWithName:size:]` to get a `UIFont` object back (as you do in the next line).

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Arial"];
```

does not return the Arial font, it returns the array of font names for the Arial font family. Check the manual [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontNamesForFamilyName:)